# Should 'Next/Previous' Buttons Be Centered Or Left Aligned?

Tags: navigation, pagination

I am trying to decide where I should put my pagination buttons on my site. I've noticed that most sites either choose left aligned, or centered buttons. Which place does the user look at first when they get to the end of a page?

Sites like Google and YouTube they have them centered:
[image: Youtube:]

Sites like Reddit and Bing they have them left aligned:
[image: Bing:]

Answer (score 1):

See where they look best based on the content you have on the page. Looking for eye breakpoints from image to text and then to the ones in the next row below.

Youtube has distinctive video thumbnails that grabs more attention, so probably it looks easier to find the navigation buttons when centered.

The second example has a line divider that gets the buttons its required attention. Scanning the lines - all left aligned.